# Monitoring storm trident

Tags: apache-storm, apache-kafka

I wish to setup a monitoring which checks the total messages in kafka queue and total messages already consumed by storm. If the difference is in thousands I need to setup an alert. Is there already such a tool available or how I setup this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Capillary](https://github.com/keenlabs/capillary) tracks a delta (how Storm is far behind from Kafka) of each partition, but it seems not supporting alerts though. You may implement your own alerts by calling its [API](https://github.com/keenlabs/capillary#api) periodically.

You can also build your own alert system from the beginning through JMX.
You can monitor `Number of messages the consumer lags behind the producer by` and alert when the lags exceed some threshold. For more information, refer to [6.6 Monitoring](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#monitoring) of Kafka documentation.

You may find some other tools from [Kafka ecosystem](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Ecosystem).